# used memory doesn't decrease when forms close

Tags: c#, winforms, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I written a program in C# (WinForms) that has many forms. I show forms in this way:

```
Form_Sell frm = new Form_Sell();
frm.Show();
```

When I show many forms, used memory of my program increased and when I close all of new forms it doesn't decrease! (I check Used memory of my program in task manager) why it happens? and how can i do?

> I used GC.Collect() in FormClosed Event of form. but it doesn't work(no effects on used memory)
>
> I test it with empty forms. no controls and nothing. but when I show form memory increases and when I close it memory doesn't decrease!

Comment: It means you have something somewhere holding onto references to those forms.  There are any number of ways that this can be happening, some explicit, some more subtle (such as closing over the form reference in a lambda when assigning event handlers to longer lived objects).  Without more info, there really isn't much for us to say.

Comment: @Servy I test it with empty forms. no controls and nothing. but when i show form memory increases and when i close it memory doesn't decrease!

Comment: It will take some time for the GC to get around to clearing up the memory in cases like that.  Don't worry about it unless the program is consuming an enormous amount of memory to the point that you start actually running out or having other problems.

Comment: @Servy my programs must runs for a few months without any interruption. and in this way used memory of my program has been too much. i worry about this.

Comment: Don't worry about memory usage  unless it's causing an actual problem. It's _virtual_ memory, in any case, not _physical_ memory.

Comment: Then you don't need to be worried about the memory being cleaned up *right away*, you just need to ensure that it gets cleaned up *eventually*, which is what the GC will do.  Test it under the circumstances in which you'll actually be using it.  If the memory is steadily increasing as you use the program over the course of several hours, then you might have a memory leak somewhere, but just because it goes up for a few seconds doesn't mean you have a problem.

Comment: What is "way too much"? If memory is ample, .Net may use more than it seems it should when there are no memory pressures. It uses it because it can, and it would be a waste of time to do what's needed to conserve memory when there is no reason to do so.

Comment: While not required for a `Form` displayed with `Show()`, you can call `Dispose()` when you're done using it. I would not recommend trying to do anything else (i.e. don't try to "force" the garbage collector to clear the memory immediately.)

Answer (score 1):

The Garbage Collector is non-deterministic.  It will only free up memory when it feels pressure to do so.  As such, just because you closed a `Form` doesn't mean it will immediately free the memory from it.

Therefore, just checking the Task Manager to see if the memory has been freed up for a single `Form` is not a good way to detect a memory leak.

To really, truly force the GC to get rid of the memory, a single `GC.Collect()` call isn't sufficient if there are items that hold native resources.  Try this instead:

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();
```

Try that, and see if your memory changes.

Comment: Note that while your statement is true in the general case, the `Form` will be disposed without needing a finalizer to run, so this shouldn't be needed *in this one case*.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use:

```
frm.Dispose();
```

by this, it will release used memory. Then run GC again and see what happens.